# Can Github Actions Which Build PRs Leak Secrets?

Tags: github-actions

Can Github actions which are automatically building untrusted PRs leak secrets they have access to?
Afaik, PRs can contribute new github actions that are run automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[It seems they cannot, even if I wanted it.](https://github.community/t5/GitHub-Actions/Make-secrets-available-to-builds-of-forks/m-p/30678)

Comment: The link is broken. Please put the solution in your answer instead of just putting a link.